# Azure Data Factory - API extraction and New column

Tags: arrays, json, api, azure-data-factory, data-transform

I need to extract data from an API to Azure and the API output is like this:

```
[{"ID":0,"SourceIndex":437,"ValueName":""},
{"ID":1,"SourceIndex":438,"ValueName":"CPSA21"},
{"ID":2,"SourceIndex":439,"ValueName":"CPSA21"},
{"ID":3,"SourceIndex":440,"ValueName":"MLPDS5"},
{"ID":4,"SourceIndex":441,"ValueName":"LEOD40"},
{"ID":5,"SourceIndex":442,"ValueName":"MCN312"}]
[1234567,
[531,65,0,12,19,3]
```

The goal is to create a new object named "Value" with the values found in the last line of the output and write to a file. Expected output:

| ID | SourceIndex | ValueName | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 437 |  | 531 |
| 1 | 438 | CPSA21 | 65 |
| 2 | 439 | CPSA21 | 0 |
| 3 | 440 | MLPDS5 | 12 |
| 4 | 441 | LEOD40 | 19 |
| 5 | 442 | MCN312 | 3 |

Is this possible to achieve using Azure Data Factory and how? Or would another solution be better? Thanks

Comment: Can u please fix your data , why do u have 1 uncompleted array is it a typo?

Comment: @SallyDabbah the information that comes from the API is like this :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo that i built for your use-case.

First i created a Json file containing your data like so:
[image]

The main idea is to join the array with the Json data and add a new key as you requested, this can be done by adding a derived column.

**ADF:**

1. created a dataflow.
2. set a parameter in dataflow **constantValues** : [531,65,0,12,19,3]
3. in derived column added the value column with the corresponding value : `$constantValues[ID + 1]` (the idea is to match id = 0 with the first value in the array).
4. saved to cached sink.

**Parameter in pipeline:**
[image]

**Derived Column:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Please check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column

Comment: Hi @Sally, thanks for your reply and explanation. I forgot to mention that all values coming from the API would be dynamic, we get different values daily

Comment: Can you please attach the response from the API without changing it?